# Pagination code on Concrete5 (Foundation5 theme)

Tags: php, if-statement, pagination, concrete5

i'm trying to fix my pagination on my Concrete5 site. I got this code on my *.php
file:

```
<?php   if ($paginate && $num > 0 && is_object($pl)) { ?>
<div class="ff-grid-4-pagination-wrapper small-12 columns pagination     centered">
<ul class="ff-grid-4-pagination pagination">
<li class="arrow"></li>
<?php   echo $paginator->getPages('li') ?>
<?php  if ($showRss): ?><li><a class="fa fa-rss" href="<?php   echo $rssUrl ?>" target="_blank"></a></li><?php  endif; ?>
<li class="arrow"></li>
</ul><!-- END .ff-grid-4-pagination -->
</div><!-- END .ff-grid-4-pagination-wrapper -->
<?php endif; ?>
```

Somehow i got error on Dreamweaver saying that my last line is wrong? What is the right way to end my code?

Sincerely,

Mika

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php if ($paginate && $num > 0 && is_object($pl)) { ?>
```

should be

```
<?php if ($paginate && $num > 0 && is_object($pl)): ?>
```

as you're terminating your script with

`<?php endif; ?>` instead of `<?php } ?>`

---

Alternatively you could change your last line from `<?php endif; ?>` to `<?php } ?>` for same reasons described above.

Moreover I suggest you to keep your syntax consistent between files, so if you use `if (...):` you should use that kind of syntax in every file.

To conclude: don't stop yourself at editor or ide error: if the hint provided by IDE isn't a good one, try to run your php code (with error reporting on) and try to understand what's the error